# Once allowed specific Java Applet in Safari, how to deny it later?

Tags: macos, java, safari, java-applet

I've checked Keychain Access, but didn't find anything related with the domain that host the Applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to deny it in /Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences. (Snow Leopard, not sure about anything earlier.)